# Centos7 yum security plugin questions

Tags: security, yum, centos-7

I feel yum security plugin is not working as claimed [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021)

For example, I know there is an outstanding CVE to openssl on my system

```
yum changelog 2017-01 openssl

Listing changelogs since 2017-01-06

==================== Available Packages ====================
1:openssl-1.0.1e-60.el7_3.1.x86_64       updates
* Mon Feb  6 07:00:00 2017 Tomáš Mráz <tmraz@redhat.com> 1.0.1e-60.1
- fix CVE-2017-3731 - DoS via truncated packets with RC4-MD5 cipher
- fix CVE-2016-8610 - DoS of single-threaded servers via excessive alerts

changelog stats. 2 pkgs, 2 source pkgs, 1 changelog
```

But when I use yum security plugin to install the particular CVE number, I get "no packages"

```
sudo yum update --cve CVE-2017-3731
No packages needed for security; 629 packages available
Resolving Dependencies
```

I know i'm running an older version

```
sudo rpm -q openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64
```

"yum info-sec" should also list the list of changes with errata but openssl with this CVE is not listed.

When I run "yum updateinfo info --cve" with CVE referenced above, it claims my system is not vulnerable

```
yum updateinfo info --cve CVE-2017-3731
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
updateinfo info done
```

It seems to the same case for kernel CVE and fixes, I can't seem to rely on the security plugin to pick any recent kernel CVEs such as [dirty cow](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/DirtyCow) or [double free](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:0403)

```
[localhost ~]$ sudo yum update --advisory=RHSA-2017:0403 
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.lax.hugeserver.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: centos.sonn.com
 * updates: cosmos.illinois.edu
No packages needed for security; 629 packages available
Resolving Dependencies

[localhost ~]$ sudo yum updateinfo --advisory=RHSA-2017:0403
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
updateinfo summary done

[localhost ~]$ sudo yum updateinfo RHSA-2017:0403
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
updateinfo info done
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm very saddened to have found out that the security plugin on CentOS7 is pretty much [useless](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51300)

Answer (score 1):

The yum security plugin will make use of security metadata found in yum repositories.

While the base CentOS repo indeed do not provide such metadata, the EPEL repository (the most popular third party repository) does.

So the yum security plugin is not entirely useless.